# Split an array in python using indexes from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, indexing

I have a 2d array of size 3 by 7 in numpy:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[4 5 6 7 8 9 0]  
[2 3 4 5 6 7 8]]
```

I also have a list that contains indexes of splitting points:

```
[1, 3]
```

Now, I want to split the array using the indexes in the list such that I get:

```
[[1 2]
[4 5]
[2 3]]

[[ 2 3 4]
[5 6 7]
[3 4 5]]

[[ 4 5 6 7]
[7 8 9 0]
[5 6 7 8]]
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with slicing, using `zip` to extract indices pairwise.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
              [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

idx = [1, 3]
idx = [0] + idx + [A.shape[1]]

res = [A[:, start: end+1] for start, end in zip(idx, idx[1:])]

print(*res, sep='\n'*2)

[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [2 3]]

[[2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]
 [3 4 5]]

[[4 5 6 7]
 [7 8 9 0]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```